# CONCAT leading 0 in case statement

Tags: sql, concatenation, case-statement, getdate, datepart

I found an error in a query I inherited from a previous coworker that I am trying to fix but it's a weird issue I haven't encountered before.. here is a snip of the original query:

```
CAST(CONCAT(DATEPART(YYYY,getdate()), 
  (CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(WW,getdate()) < 10 
    THEN CONCAT('0', DATEPART(WW,getdate())) 
    ELSE DATEPART(WW,getdate()) 
   END)
) AS INT)
```

When getdate() = 2021-01-08 10:16:41.440 the query results in

```
20212
```

Expected result should be

```
202102
```

I found the issue relies in in the CASE statement. When I tried to change the THEN clause to

```
CAST(CONCAT(DATEPART(YYYY,getdate()), 
  (CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(WW,getdate()) < 10 
    THEN RIGHT('0'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(WW,getdate())),2) 
    ELSE DATEPART(WW,getdate()) 
   END)
) AS INT)
```

I still get

```
20212
```

But when I run

```
SELECT RIGHT('0'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(WW,getdate())),2)
```

I get

```
02
```

Can someone explain this? Why does it work outside of the CASE statement, but not within?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` expressions return a single value and that has a single type.  If any of the return values are numbers, then the return value is a number, not a string.

To get a string, use `datename()`:

```
(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WW, getdate()) < 10 
      THEN CONCAT('0', DATENAME(WW,getdate())) 
      ELSE DATENAME(WW, getdate()) 
 END)
```

Or you could simplify your logic:

```
RIGHT(CONCAT('0', DATENAME(WW, getdate()), 2)
```

Or simplify everything.  For instance, a number might be sufficient:

```
YEAR(GETDATE()) * 100 + DATEPART(WW, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has implicit cast to `INT`:

```
CAST(CONCAT(DATEPART(YYYY,getdate()), 
  (CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(WW,getdate()) < 10 
    THEN RIGHT('0'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(WW,getdate())),2) 
    ELSE CAST(DATEPART(WW,getdate()) AS VARCHAR(2))  -- adding explicit cast here
   END)
) AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can advice the simple way:

```
SELECT 
 CAST(
   CONCAT(
     DATEPART(YYYY,getdate()), 
     RIGHT(CONCAT('0000', DATEPART(WW,getdate())), 2)
) AS INT);
```

You can [try T-SQL here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=513ae0cd5b61717b4026c1b054481ecd&php_version=null&sql_version=mssql2017)